# Can I turn off git checkout's "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/whatever' by N commits" message?

Tags: git

If I have a git repository with a branch `whatever`, and that branch is tied by `git remote` to another branch on a remote (upstream) repo, then when I switch to that branch, I get something like:

```
[git checkout whatever]
Switched to branch 'whatever'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/whatever' by 5 commits.

[git status]
On branch whatever
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/whatever' by 5 commits.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I'd like to know: **is it possible to hide the "ahead by 5 commits" count for `git checkout`?** I already know that it is possible for `git status` with `git status --no-ahead-behind` or the *gitconfig* configuration option `status.aheadBehind`, but I'd like to know if something similar is possible for `git checkout`. Preferably, it would be through a *gitconfig* option so I don't have to define a command alias or continually retype a command option.

---

Ideas I've tried:

- `git checkout --quiet` / `-q` : That does suppress the "ahead by 5 commits" message, but unfortunately it also hides all the other output, which I'd like to keep if I can.
- `advice.statusHints` option in *gitconfig*: That doesn't have any effect on the "ahead by 5 commits" message.

Comment: Why do I care about this? At times, I work in very large git repos, in which `git status` produces messages like: `It took 3.85 seconds to compute the branch ahead/behind values. You can use '--no-ahead-behind' to avoid this.` I'd like to be able to avoid that slowdown for both `git checkout` and `git status`.

Comment: You are on the latest version of git I assume?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Unfortunately, no, I do not have the latest version of git on the computer I need this for. For technical reasons, I must use a customized version of git (currently based on 2.20.1 from December 2018) to access the large repos I'm concerned about. Are there performance improvements in the past few months of git I could benefit from?

Comment: I do not get this message when I checkout a branch that is ahead of its upstream. I just get `Switched to branch 'issue/#880'`... though I do get it checking out `master`. This is `git version 2.21.0`. Maybe it's something about your customized version of git?

Comment: For a known branch *foo*, `git -c branch.foo.remote= status` and `git -c branch.foo.remote= checkout foo` can work. But it's not a good solution.

Comment: @Schwern I just checked on a computer running stock git (the Windows binary download from https://git-scm.com; `git version 2.21.0.windows.1`) and I do get the ahead/behind messages on non-master branches. `Switched to branch 'fix-32767' / Your branch is behind 'origin/fix-32767' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.` Maybe your branch `issue/#880` was up to date with the remote as far as git knew?

Comment: @ElpieKay maybe your solution _might_ be good? I agree that it's perhaps too heavyweight to suppress any knowledge of the remote repo entirely, but I don't know what if any negative consequences would arise for `checkout [branch name]` or `status` with that option.

Comment: Probably no speed benefit in the latest version then, just last time I saw a question like this it turned out the person was using git like pre-alpha or some really old version.

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
git branch --unset-upstream whatever
```

to permanently dissociate branch `whatever` from its upstream branch. Then the ahead/behind counts will not be computed anymore.

Another consequence is that plain

```
git pull
```

does not know anymore which remote branch to merge when you are on branch `whatever`.